# Django model instance deleted if exception raises

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using Django==1.11.3, If exception is raised while accessing instance method it deletes object. Below is an example

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    response = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    @classmethod
    def add_api_response(cls, key, response):

        obj = cls.objects.create(
            key=key,response=response
        )
        return obj


 response_data = SomeModel.add_api_response(
                key=some_key,
                response=some_response
            )

# ^ above codes creates a object with id `x`
response_data.get() # OR response_data.any_unknown()
# ^ above codes deletes it
```

I am new to Django please guide if its expected behavior i.e it deletes the model on raising exception or i should be missing any exception hook?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: in your `add_api_response` method instead of `cls.objects.create..` try `SomeModel.objects.create...`. Also return the obj after creating it.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal yeah missed that return while pasting example(edited now, thanks), tried with `SomeModel.objects.create` still same behavior

Comment: why do you need `response_data.get()`. just `response_data` is enough. It's the object just created.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal my question is : if i use `response_data.get()` why it deletes the model? is it expected behavior of Django model?

Comment: no its not. Delete happens when you do `obj.delete()` or `del obj`. Are you sure it's actually getting deleted, try looking in your database manually.

Comment: I agree with @VaibhavVishal. Why do you think that the object is deleted? It should raise  `SomeModel has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: Yes thats what i thought but in my current app scenario its generating exception and deleting as well. May be some post hooks configured and i am missing those in current scenario

Comment: are you using custom transaction management? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/transactions/ if so on exception transaction is rolled back hence data will be deleted from DB

Comment: Thanks @miki725 i should be missing transaction hook in my repo however i am unable to find it directly atm.